# How to find out the PredType of a dataset in HDF5 using the C++ library

Tags: c++, hdf5

So I just found out, that if I write an `unsigned char` array into a `float` dataset in my HDF5 file the library does not complain. Therefore, I want to check before I write that the two are actually compatible. So for my `unsigned char` array I have the corresponding `PredType`. But the dataset does not offer an obvious way to get the `PredType`, if I am not mistaken.

**Question:** Given a `H5::Dataset`, how do I obtain the `PredType` that was used to initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code on https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/readdata_8cpp-example.html demonstrates how to do this.

In summary; you can find the "class" of the data stored using `DataSet::getTypeClass()` function. This "class" however does not fully define the data type because it does not let you infer the size (i.e. 8-bits, 32-bits...etc.) or the sign representation (i.e. unsigned, 2's complement) for native types.

In the case of float; you also need to use `DataSet::getFloatType()` and use `FloatType::getSize()` to infer if the data type is `PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT` or `PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE` as in:

```
auto dataClass = dataSet.getTypeClass();

if(dataClass == H5T_FLOAT)
{
    auto floatType = dataSet.getFloatType();

    size_t byteSize = floatType.getSize();

    if(byteSize == 4) 
    {
         // use PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT to write
    }
    else if(byteSize == 8)
    { 
         // use PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE to write
    }
}
```

For the sign representation of integers, you need to use `IntType::getSign()`.

Comment: Makes you wonder why this is not included as a feature in the HDF5-Library. Is your method correct all the times? Or are there assumptions you used?

Comment: I can't see any case that it would fail right now, I will update the post if I do.

Comment: @KaanC.Fidan `PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT` and `PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE` are not the only possible float types in HDF5, so you’re assuming that it’s one of those two. For example, if the floats in the HDF5 file have a different endianness than `NATIVE_FLOAT`/`NATIVE_DOUBLE` (e. g. `PredType::IEEE_F64BE` vs. `PredType::IEEE_F64LE`), this will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving the problem (i.e. to find out the data type of a HDF5 dataset) is to use the tool [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) for C++ as follows (this example assumes that the file `example.h5` and dataset `my_dataset` already exist):

```
// include HDFql C++ header file (make sure it can be found by the C++ compiler)
#include <iostream>
#include "HDFql.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data_type;

    // get data type of dataset "my_dataset" from HDF5 file "example.h5" and populate HDFql default cursor with it
    HDFql::execute("SHOW DATA TYPE example.h5 my_dataset");

    // move HDFql default cursor to first position
    HDFql::cursorFirst();

    // retrieve data type from HDFql default cursor
    data_type = *HDFql::cursorGetInt();

    // print message according to data type
    if (data_type == HDFql::TinyInt || data_type == HDFql::VarTinyInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is a char";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::UnsignedTinyInt || data_type == HDFql::UnsignedVarTinyInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is an unsigned char";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::SmallInt || data_type == HDFql::VarSmallInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is a short";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::UnsignedSmallInt || data_type == HDFql::UnsignedVarSmallInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is an unsigned short";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Int || data_type == HDFql::VarInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is an int";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::UnsignedInt || data_type == HDFql::UnsignedVarInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is an unsigned int";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::BigInt || data_type == HDFql::VarBigInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is a long long";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::UnsignedBigInt || data_type == HDFql::UnsignedVarBigInt)
        std::cout << "Data type is an unsigned long long";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Float || data_type == HDFql::VarFloat)
        std::cout << "Data type is a float";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Double || data_type == HDFql::VarDouble)
        std::cout << "Data type is a double";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Char || data_type == HDFql::VarChar)
        std::cout << "Data type is a char";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Opaque)
        std::cout << "Data type is an opaque";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Enumeration)
        std::cout << "Data type is an enumeration";
    else if (data_type == HDFql::Compound)
        std::cout << "Data type is a compound";
    else
        std::cout << "Unknown data type";

    return 0;
}
```

Eventually, in case you need to get the endianness or the size of the dataset `my_dataset`, execute `HDFql::execute("SHOW ENDIANNESS example.h5 my_dataset");` or `HDFql::execute("SHOW SIZE example.h5 my_dataset");`.