# Get the C++ data type found in HDF5 dataset

Tags: types, dataset, hdf5

Wondering how to get HDF5 dataset values interpreted as standard and/or primitive C++ data types?

I have a .mat file that holds some user setting info.  I'm not familiar with Matlab (.mat files) or HDF5. Some of that data would be doubles, booleans, strings or int types looking at the open file in Matlab.

I figured out how to read the file in using HDF5 and open a DataSet.  I've also figured out how to iterate all the objects in the DataSet.  But I just need to know what each type is so I can perform the appropriate read calls.

Below is the code I have so far that works.

```
H5::DataSet data_set;
    try
    {
        data_set = file->openDataSet("/USER_SETTINGS/OUTPUT_PATH");
    }
    catch (H5::LocationException e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    H5::DataSpace data_space = data_set.getSpace();
    H5::DataType data_type = data_set.getDataType();
    
    //Some other code not relevant to my question to read out rtnStringValue to an actual std::string

    data_set.read(rtnStringValue, data_type, data_space); //This call is specific to returning a string value.
```

I know to call the correct DataSet overload read function call because I know "OUTPUT_PATH" is a string.

My problem is what if I don't know what type the "/USER_SETTINGS/<some other thing>" contains?  There is a different overload data_set.read function for other data types.

Comment: Not a direct answer but: Normally that question doesn't arise because HDF5 converts between types. You define what type you want, HDF5 either converts or causes an error. So i doesn't matter whether the content is stored as float or double, for example, -- you want double, you get double. And when dealing with new data sources, the normal approach would be to inspect the layout with one of the viewers (e.g. ```h5ls -r file.h5```), then program the IO for the values you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out what I am looking for.  Got some answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129479/how-to-find-out-the-predtype-of-a-dataset-in-hdf5-using-the-c-library), and then pieced together some other clues by looking at the .mat file in HDFView.

[image]

I came up with this that works . . .

```
auto dataClass = data_set.getTypeClass();

if (dataClass == H5T_FLOAT)
{
    auto floatType = data_set.getFloatType();
    size_t byteSize = floatType.getSize();

    if (byteSize == 4)
    {
        type = "float";
    }
    else if (byteSize == 8)
    {
        type = "double";
    }
}
else if (dataClass == H5T_INTEGER)
{
    auto intType = data_set.getIntType();
    size_t byteSize = intType.getSize();

    if (byteSize == 1)
    {
        type = "uint8";
    }
    else if (byteSize == 2)
    {
        type = "char";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can easily be solved using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) in C++:

```
int type;

HDFql::execute("SELECT FROM /USER_SETTINGS/DSET");

type = HDFql::cursorGetDataType();

if (type == HDFql::Int)
{
    std::cout << "The dataset is an integer with value " << *HDFql::cursorGetInt() << std::endl;
}
else if (type == HDFql::Float)
{
    std::cout << "The dataset is a float with value " << *HDFql::cursorGetFloat() << std::endl;
}
else if (type == HDFql::Varchar)
{
    std::cout << "The dataset is a variable char (string) with value " << HDFql::cursorGetChar() << std::endl;
}
(...)
```